# why the segue is not firing in this context

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

i drag and drop a segue from the yellow part of a view controller to another view controller, and by the yellow part i mean this:
[image]

then i make a networking call to a server, i handle the response, then i want to fire the segue, i do this:

```
 let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            // bla bla here

self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SegueIdentifier.receivedResponse.rawValue, sender: self)
                }catch {

                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
```

as you see, i am calling `perform segue`

then i add `prepareForSegue`

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let identifier = segue.identifier
        if let identifier = identifier {
            switch identifier {
            case SegueIdentifier.receivedResponse.rawValue:
                let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! ResponsesTableViewController
                destination.responses = self.responses
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

i put break point, all the lines inside the `prepareForSegue` all the way until the break, all executed but the second view controller didn't show

Comment: What is in your do-catch block? If your code throws, that performSegue will never be executed. And you should switch to the main queue to performSegue.

Comment: Is your session configured to use a delegate queue?

Comment: @lan there is no excpetoni thrown, beause as i told u, the prepareForSegue is executed

Comment: @matt i guess not because my session is : `let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()`

Comment: why minues to the question? i showed u what i tried

Comment: You should dispatch the `performSegueWithIdentifier` on the main queue

Comment: @Paulw11 do you mean that istead of calling the perform segue with identifer inside the clouser, i should call a function inside the view controller, and that functoin will call the perform segue with identifer ?

Comment: No, in the closure use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SegueIdentifier.receivedResponse.rawValue, sender: self)})`.  The completion handler is going to be running on a background queue.  UI operations need to happen on the main queue

Comment: @Paulw11 yes thank you that solve the problem, please write a question and i will accept it. please could u tell me why my way was wrong? is it that i was in not first thread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The completion handler is going to be running on a background queue. UI operations need to happen on the main queue.  So, in your completion handler closure use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SegueIdentifier.receivedResponse.rawValue, sender: self)
})
```

Comment: so everytime i call calouser it will be in this background queue? or just in the session.data with task function? also i see that there is background queue and you said main queue, is there other queues?

Comment: Many completion handlers are called on background queues but not always.  The Parse.com framework, for example, dispatches completion handlers on the main queue for you.  There are a number of default queues and you can create your own.   See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Right, this is what I was getting at with my comment too.